# How to run Espresso tests generated by Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

In Android Studio 3.1.2, I created an Espresso test using the test recorder.
When running the test (correct run configuration), I get

```
E/TestLoader: Could not find class: "my.package.MyClassTest"
```

in the log though this is the test class's package and name. Then the Run/Test window shows

```
Empty test suite
```

How to run the tests?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the recorder put the tests in the wrong place:

```
src/androidTestDebug/aidl/my/package/MyClassTest
```

but correct is

```
src/androidTest/java/my/package/MyClassTest
```

without any further configuration. For reference, this is the module's `build.gradle` with the test dependencies:

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

}
```